# How to override versionCode for ABI filters with gradle plugin 3.0.0-beta1?

Tags: android-studio-3.0, android-gradle-3.0

I have the following defined in my build.gradle for overriding the `versionCode` based on the `ABI`.

```
import com.android.build.OutputFile

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def defaultCode = android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        def filter = output.getFilter(OutputFile.FilterType.ABI)
        def abiMultiplier = project.ext.versionCodes.get(filter)
        if (abiMultiplier == null) {
            abiMultiplier = 1
        }
        output.versionCodeOverride = abiMultiplier * 100000000 + defaultCode
    }
}
```

This works with the 2.3 gradle plugin, but not with Android Studio 3.0 beta 1, using 3.0.0-beta1 gradle plugin with gradle 4.1, giving me the follow error:

> Could not find method getFilter() for arguments [ABI] on
>   ApkVariantOutputImpl_Decorated{apkData=FullSplit{type=FULL_SPLIT,
>   fullName=developmentArm64-v8aDebug, filters=[FilterDataImpl{type=ABI,
>   value=arm64-v8a}]}} of type
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApkVariantOutputImpl.

The [migration documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_api) seems to indicate that this might be somewhat broken?  I've tried also tried:

> def filter = output.getFilter(ApkVariantOutput.ABI)

and casting `output` to `ApkVariantOutput` to no avail (same error).

Comment: This seems like a bug, so I filed a ticket over here - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64600304

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to change `OutputFile.FilterType.ABI` to `OutputFile.ABI`, which uses the string representation of the FilterType enum.